# ¿Como hacer una consulta sql que traiga solo traiga los primeros datos de una columna?

Tags: sql, select, ms-access

Tengo una tabla con dos columnas y quiero traer de la segunda columna todos los datos númericos hasta el primer dato de tipo texto.

Ejemplo:

```
Colum1  |   Colum2 
------------------
01      |   02MEX
```

Para después en una nueva columna generar una multiplicación de estas dos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Es decir, en este ejemplo, ¿estás queriendo multiplicar 1524 por 1,500? (de hecho no sé si la coma allí representa un separador de miles o separa el entero de la parte decimal)

Comment: Qué tienen que ver los datos que publicas como ejemplo con lo de la imagen? pregunto porque 01 * 02 = 2, y no hay una explicación clara de cómo eso se relaciona con 1524, 1500, 20 o el número que sea al que quieres llegar de la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar queries anidadas para obtener el resultado con la columna ya convertida a Decimal. Para ello puedes utilizar SUBSTRING_INDEX Y REPLACE para extraer la parte numérica y luego utilizar CAST para convertirlo a decimal.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column1 * Column2  as Multiplication
from (
    select Column1 , CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column2, ' ', 1), ',', ''), '.', '') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Column2  
    from your_table
) t
```

Puedes probarlo utilizando esta version con dummy data:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column1 * Column2  as Multiplication
from (
    select Column1 , CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column2, ' ', 1), ',', ''), '.', '') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Column2  
    from (
    select 1524 as Column1, '1,500 ml / 20 dias' as Column2
    union all
    select 1524 as Column1, '1,400 ml / 30 dias' as Column2
    ) t 
) tt
```

Comment: Gracias lo probaré de esa forma

Answer (score -1):

me funciono con:

```
Select LEFT (campo, 5)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer], saludos.